# Spring Integration - SpelEvaluationException: The operator 'ADD' is not supported between objects of type 'java.lang.String' and 'null'

Tags: java, spring, batch-file, ftp, integration

I have a Spring batch/integration job that's supposed to poll an FTP server, get all .txt-files, transform them using a Spring Batch component and then put them on a queue (implemented with ActiveMQ). However, I'm getting this error when trying to retrieve a file from the FTP area:

```
ERROR [org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler] - <org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1030E:(pos 0): The operator 'ADD' is not supported between objects of type 'java.lang.String' and 'null'
```

Relevant spring xml config (lots of code omitted for clarity):

```
<beans>

<!-- Spring integration setup -->

   <int:channel id="outboundJobRequestChannel"/>
   <int:channel id="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>
   <int:channel id="inboundFileChannel"/>

   <batch-int:job-launching-gateway request-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel"
                               reply-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel"
                               job-launcher="jobLauncher" />

   <int:logging-channel-adapter channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>

   <int:transformer input-channel="ftpChannel"
               output-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel"
               method="toRequest">

       <bean class="package.FileMessageToJobRequest">
         <constructor-arg index="0" ref="myJob" />
         <constructor-arg index="1" value="input.file.name" />
       </bean>
   </int:transformer>  

   <bean id="ftpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
      <property name="host" value="${import.ftp.host}" />
      <property name="port" value="${import.ftp.port}" />
      <property name="username" value="${import.ftp.username}" />
      <property name="password" value="${import.ftp.password}" />
   </bean>

   <int:channel id="ftpChannel" />

   <int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
       channel="ftpChannel"
       session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
       auto-create-local-directory="true"
       delete-remote-files="false"
       filename-pattern="*.txt"
       remote-directory="${import.ftp.remotefolder}"
       local-filename-generator-expression="+#this"
       temporary-file-suffix=".reading"
       local-directory="${ftp.localdir}">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
   </int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>


  <!-- Spring batch job setup -->

  <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
  </bean>

  <batch:job-repository id="jobRepository" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

  <batch:job id="myJob">
   <batch:step id="textToXmlStep" next="addToQueueStep">
     <batch:tasklet>
       <batch:chunk reader="filradReader" writer="multiResourceWriter" commit-interval="${job.commit.interval}" />  
     </batch:tasklet>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="stepListener"/>
    </batch:listeners>
   </batch:step>
   <batch:step id="addToQueueStep">
    <batch:tasklet ref="addFilesToQueueTasklet" />
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="stepListener"/>
    </batch:listeners>
   </batch:step>
   <batch:listeners>
      <batch:listener ref="jobListener"/>
   </batch:listeners>
  </batch:job>

  <bean id="filradReader" scope="step" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="file://#{jobParameters['input.file.name']}" /> 
    <property name="lineMapper" ref="filradCompositeLineMapper"/>
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="1"/>
    <property name="skippedLinesCallback" ref="callbackHandler"/>
    <property name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="addFilesToQueueTasklet" class="package.FilesToMqTasklet">
    <property name="filesBaseDir" value="${files.outputdir}\xml" />
    <property name="messageProducer" ref="messageProducer"/>
  </bean>


  <!-- ActiveMQ setup -->

  <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
    p:brokerURL="${broker.url}" />

  <bean id="destination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="queue" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"
    p:connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory"
    p:defaultDestination-ref="destination" />

  <bean id="messageProducer" class="package.FileMessageProducer"
    p:jmsTemplate-ref="jmsTemplate" />

  <bean id="messageListener" class="package.FileMessageListener" />

  <jms:listener-container concurrency="5-50">
    <jms:listener destination="queue" ref="messageListener"/>
  </jms:listener-container>

</beans>
```

(part of) FileMessageToJobRequest.java:

```
public FileMessageToJobRequest(final Job job, final String fileParameterName){
        this.job = job;
        this.fileParameterName = fileParameterName;
    }

    public JobLaunchRequest toRequest(Message<File> message) {
        JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder =
            new JobParametersBuilder();

        jobParametersBuilder.addString(fileParameterName,
            message.getPayload().getAbsolutePath()).addDate("run.date", new Date());

        return new JobLaunchRequest(job, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
    }
```

(part of) FileMessageProducer.java:

```
public class FileMessageProducer {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileMessageProducer.class);

    protected JmsTemplate jmsTemplate; 

    public void sendFile(final File file) throws JMSException {
        jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage(file); 
                message.setStringProperty("fileName", file.getName());
                logger.info("Sent message: "+message.getStringProperty("fileName"));
                return message;
            }
        });

    }
```

(part of) FileMessageListener.java:

```
public class FileMessageListener implements MessageListener {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileMessageListener.class);

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            logger.info("Received file " + message.getStringProperty("fileName"));
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I'm testing this setup with

```
public class FileListener {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileListener.class);
    private static final String CONFIG = "/launch-context.xml";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        logger.debug("FileListener started");
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONFIG);
    }
}
```

Complete stack trace:

```
2015-03-09 10:06:52,879 INFO [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext] - <Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@644b27ad: startup date [Mon Mar 09 10:06:52 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy>
2015-03-09 10:06:52,931 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - <Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [launch-context.xml]>
2015-03-09 10:06:53,111 INFO [org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner] - <JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning>
2015-03-09 10:06:53,187 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - <Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/datasource-beans.xml]>
2015-03-09 10:06:53,228 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - <Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/job.xml]>
2015-03-09 10:06:53,303 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/datasource-beans.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/job.xml]]>
2015-03-09 10:06:53,321 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Overriding bean definition for bean 'myJob': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.SimpleFlowFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.JobParserJobFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]>
2015-03-09 10:06:53,326 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - <Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/queue.xml]>
2015-03-09 10:06:54,043 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - <Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/integration.xml]>
2015-03-09 10:06:54,367 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] - <Loading properties file from URL [file:/.../externalConfig/dev/application.properties]>
2015-03-09 10:06:54,386 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Overriding bean definition for bean 'stepListener': replacing [Generic bean: class [package.StepListener]; scope=step; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/job.xml]] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/job.xml]]>
2015-03-09 10:06:54,386 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Overriding bean definition for bean 'filradReader': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader]; scope=step; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/job.xml]] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/job.xml]]>
2015-03-09 10:06:54,387 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Overriding bean definition for bean 'multiResourceWriter': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemWriter]; scope=step; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/job.xml]] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/job.xml]]>
2015-03-09 10:06:54,387 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Overriding bean definition for bean 'filradXmlWriter': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter]; scope=step; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=false; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/job.xml]] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/job.xml]]>
2015-03-09 10:06:54,391 INFO [org.springframework.integration.config.xml.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor] - <No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.>
2015-03-09 10:06:54,392 INFO [org.springframework.integration.config.xml.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor] - <No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.>
2015-03-09 10:06:54,402 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] - <JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring>
2015-03-09 10:06:54,415 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6112f78c: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer#0,dataSource,transactionManager,jobLauncher,org.springframework.batch.core.scope.internalStepScope,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer,org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.CoreNamespacePostProcessor,jobRepository,filradSetMapper,stepListener,jobListener,callbackHandler,suffixCreator,filradProcessor,textToXmlStep,addToQueueStep,myJob,multiResourceReader,filradReader,filradCompositeLineMapper,taxiTokenizer,biljettTokenizer,rullstolTokenizer,multiResourceWriter,filradXmlWriter,filradTyperValidMarshaller,addFilesToQueueTasklet,connectionFactory,destination,jmsTemplate,messageProducer,messageListener,org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0,channelInitializer,$autoCreateChannelCandidates,org.springframework.integration.internalDefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,outboundJobRequestChannel,jobLaunchReplyChannel,inboundFileChannel,org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingGateway#0,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler#0,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1,org.springframework.integration.config.TransformerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2,ftpClientFactory,ftpChannel,org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger#0,ftpInbound,ftpController,scopedTarget.stepListener,scopedTarget.filradReader,scopedTarget.multiResourceWriter,scopedTarget.filradXmlWriter,nullChannel,errorChannel,_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger,taskScheduler,org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0]; root of factory hierarchy>
2015-03-09 10:06:54,597 INFO [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator] - <Executing SQL script from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/jesleh/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-core/2.2.3.RELEASE/spring-batch-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-hsqldb.sql]>
2015-03-09 10:06:54,601 INFO [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator] - <Done executing SQL script from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/jesleh/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-core/2.2.3.RELEASE/spring-batch-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-hsqldb.sql] in 4 ms.>
2015-03-09 10:06:54,601 INFO [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator] - <Executing SQL script from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/jesleh/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-core/2.2.3.RELEASE/spring-batch-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql]>
2015-03-09 10:06:54,614 INFO [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator] - <Done executing SQL script from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/jesleh/.m2/repository/org/springframework/batch/spring-batch-core/2.2.3.RELEASE/spring-batch-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql] in 12 ms.>
2015-03-09 10:06:54,663 INFO [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean] - <No database type set, using meta data indicating: HSQL>
2015-03-09 10:06:54,797 INFO [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher] - <No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.>
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2015-03-09 10:06:55,027 INFO [org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller] - <Creating JAXBContext with classes to be bound [class package.Filrad]>
2015-03-09 10:06:55,490 INFO [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler] - <Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler'>
2015-03-09 10:06:55,498 INFO [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor] - <Starting beans in phase -2147483648>
2015-03-09 10:06:55,498 INFO [org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer] - <Adding {message-handler} as a subscriber to the 'outboundJobRequestChannel' channel>
2015-03-09 10:06:55,498 INFO [org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel] - <Channel 'outboundJobRequestChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).>
2015-03-09 10:06:55,498 INFO [org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer] - <started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0>
2015-03-09 10:06:55,498 INFO [org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer] - <Adding {logging-channel-adapter} as a subscriber to the 'jobLaunchReplyChannel' channel>
2015-03-09 10:06:55,498 INFO [org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel] - <Channel 'jobLaunchReplyChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).>
2015-03-09 10:06:55,498 INFO [org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer] - <started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1>
2015-03-09 10:06:55,498 INFO [org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer] - <Adding {transformer} as a subscriber to the 'ftpChannel' channel>
2015-03-09 10:06:55,498 INFO [org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel] - <Channel 'ftpChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).>
2015-03-09 10:06:55,498 INFO [org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer] - <started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2>
2015-03-09 10:06:55,498 INFO [org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer] - <Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel>
2015-03-09 10:06:55,498 INFO [org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel] - <Channel 'errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).>
2015-03-09 10:06:55,498 INFO [org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer] - <started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger>
2015-03-09 10:06:55,499 INFO [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor] - <Starting beans in phase 2147483647>
2015-03-09 10:06:55,755 INFO [org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter] - <started ftpInbound>
2015-03-09 10:07:10,041 ERROR [org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler] - <org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1030E:(pos 0): The operator 'ADD' is not supported between objects of type 'java.lang.String' and 'null'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ExpressionState.operate(ExpressionState.java:191)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpPlus.getValueInternal(OpPlus.java:59)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.generateLocalFileName(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:228)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.copyFileToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:174)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.receive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:146)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.java:67)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:144)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:236)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:231)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:51)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The job itself (reading and transforming .txt-files to xml output) works, I've run that step separately without problems. The problem seems to lie in reading files from the FTP area. I've also tried googling the problem but can't find anything. I realize this is a big request but if anyone has any idea I'd be really happy. Thanks.

Comment: I guess the problem might be here. local-filename-generator-expression="+#this". Try providing a sample value below and try it out. ` local-filename-generator-expression="'sample'+#this"`

Comment: Thank you @minion! Should have known it had something to do with SpEL expressions from the stacktrace. However, now I keep getting another exception: SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 8): Method call: Method toRequest(java.io.File) cannot be found on package.FileMessageToJobRequest type. Any idea why this isn't working? I'm trying to receive the file as a Message with the file name as payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using

```
  <int:service-activator id="runJob" method="launch" input-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel"
        output-channel="statuses">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingMessageHandler">
            <constructor-arg ref="jobLauncher"/>
        </bean>
    </int:service-activator>
```

instead of

```
<batch-int:job-launching-gateway request-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel"
                                   reply-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel"
                                   job-launcher="jobLauncher" />
```

and then changing the argument of the toRequest method to (java.io.File file). Now everything works as expected. Thank you @minion for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have put it as an answer.

First error was because of null being passed while doing the operation  `local-filename-generator-expression="+#this`". Trying to provide value seems to solve it `local-filename-generator-expression="'sample'+#this"`.

Second error in your comment was because of the method signature. Below method takes `Message<File> message` as arg whereas caller of it passing io.File as arg. Hence the error. I am not sure based on the info provided, where the caller is, but this should give you the gist of the error.

```
public JobLaunchRequest toRequest(Message<File> message) {
        JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder =
            new JobParametersBuilder();
```

Comment: Yes, the first part is correct. Thank you! I understand the logical error of the second part, that the caller is looking for a toRequest method with a File as argument, and can't find it. However I can't understand why tries to send a File instead of a Message<File> as it should. I've used [this github project](https://github.com/SpringOne2GX-2014/spring-batch-performance-tuning/tree/master/sample_code/message-job-launch) as a basis for my project, and this creates a Message<File> while my job creates a File, and I don't understand the differences in our projects.

Comment: Change the above method signature to java.io.File if your job creates a file instead of messgae<File>, like below. `public JobLaunchRequest toRequest(java.io.File file)` and try rest of the processing.

Comment: I've tried that, but that only results in: `<org.springframework.batch.integration.launch.JobLaunchingGateway#0 received message: [Payload=JobLaunchRequest: myJob, parameters={input.file.name=C:\..(omitted)..txt, run.date=1425998766007}][Headers={timestamp=1425998766008, id=0bfe4346-9a79-40dc-937a-22307620a0a1}]>
2015-03-10 15:46:06,010 ERROR [org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler] - <java.lang.AbstractMethodError
 at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)`

Comment: [Full stacktrace here](http://pastebin.com/RK0QMWZE). Also, thank you so much @minion for taking the time to help me out, very much appreciated.

Comment: The github example code creates a message and logs it like this: `file.FileReadingMessageSource:264 - Created message: [[Payload File content=C:\...\test.txt][Headers={id=92066dd3-3310-8b6d-75bc-2cc45c2b1669, timestamp=1426003496396}]]`while my code logs:  
`[org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource] - <Created message: [[Payload=C:\...\test.txt][Headers={timestamp=1425998766000, id=e3ef074b-4c37-4e40-a9a4-ddb8e00c79d7}]]>`. Why does my code lack `File content`, and what does that mean?